# Variable interpolation appears not to work

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple function that returns a list of files in a directory and its subdirectories. I shamelessly stole the majority of this function from another SO poster. I am using Python 2.6.4.

```
def getFiles(Asite):
    # returns a list of config files
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    mypath = '/etc/config/' + Asite
    print mypath
    files = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
    return files
```

The function simply returns an empty list, `[]`. It appears that the `mypath` variable is not being interpolated by the `listdir()` and `isfile()` functions. Before anyone asks, yes, I have verified that there are in fact files located at `mypath`. Why is my `files` array empty?

Comment: What does "interpolation" mean in this context?

Comment: why don't you use the `os.walk` function to get all the files? because `os.listdir` goes only one level

Comment: Maybe I am using "interpolation" incorrectly, but I mean that listdir() and join() should be using the value of the mypath variable, not the string 'mypath'.

Comment: @abhishekgarg - I will happily make the change to os.walk, if I can get the code working for os.listdir first, thanks for that info

Comment: What does `print mypath` print?

Comment: The code works, given correct file paths. I suspect it is a problem with the paths you're using.

Comment: "variable interpolation" is not the right term here (it's normally used for languages that let you put variables in quoted strings, like Perl - e.g. `$mypath = "/etc/config/$Asite"`). This is just string concatenation.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - print mypath prints "/etc/config/sitename"

Comment: Break down the code and try it a piece at a time to see where it's not doing what you expect. For example, try `print listdir(mypath)` and see what it produces. If that's working, write a `for` loop over the results where you print the result of `isfile(join(mypath,f))`. Are the files regular files or perhaps symlinks?

Comment: "[Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)" is definitely not the word you're going for here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your helpful comments. It turns out that the directory I was searching in only had sudirectories in it, but not files. So os.listdir() didn't work for searching subdirectories, as it only goes one level (thank you abhishekgarg). I ended up using the code below, which worked great (which I also found on SO, and modified a bit).

```
def getFiles(Asite):
    # returns a list of config files
    files = []
    mypath = '/share/profile/base/sol-10-sparc-base/config/' + Asite
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mypath):
            for filename in filenames:
                    pfile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
                    files.append(pfile[len(mypath):])
    return files
```